# Naive implementation of decorator pattern in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, design-patterns, decorator

I have read from the book *Cocoa Design Patterns* that the decorator pattern is used in many `Cocoa` classes, including `NSAttributedString` (which does not inherit from `NSString`). I [looked at an implementation `NSAttributedString.m`](http://www.koders.com/objectivec/fid6E9728FBD2B4BDFC1619FCCB27155000FDBEED8A.aspx) and it was over my head, but I would be interested to know if anyone on SO has successfully implemented this pattern AND they are willing to share.

The requirements are adapted from [this decorator pattern reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Decorator_UML_class_diagram.svg) and since there are no abstract classes in Objective-C, the `Component` and `Decorator` should be suitably similar enough to abstract classes and serve their original purpose (i.e. I don't think they can be protocols, because you have to be able to do `[super operation]`.

I would be really thrilled to see some of your implementations of decorator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used it in one of my app where i had multiple representation of a cell
i have a cell that had a border, and a cell that had had additional buttons and a cell that had a textured image
I also needed to change them at a click of a button

Here is some of the code i used

```
//CustomCell.h
@interface CustomCell : UIView

//CustomCell.m
@implementation CustomCell

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //Draw the normal images on the cell
}

@end
```

And for Custom Cell With Border

```
//CellWithBorder.h
@interface CellWithBorder : CustomCell
{
    CustomCell *aCell;
}

//CellWithBorder.m
@implementation CellWithBorder

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //Draw the border
    //inset the rect to draw the original cell
    CGRect insetRect = CGRectInset(rect, 10, 10);
    [aCell drawRect:insetRect];
}
```

Now in my view controller, i would do the following

```
CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
CellWithBorder *cellWithBorder = [[CellWithBorder alloc] initWithCell:cell];
```

If later on i wanted to switch to another cell i would do

```
CellWithTexture *cellWithBorder = [[CellWithTexture alloc] initWithCell:cellWithBorder.cell];
```

Comment: @RobNapier No this is decorator, a decorator is a "subclass" that "has a" reference to the superclass, decorator also must conform to the superclass interface

Comment: @RobNapier :), i love your book btw